# Proof of $\sqrt a -\sqrt{a-1} <\sqrt{a-2} -\sqrt{a-3}$ for $a\ge3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Given that $a\ge3,$ prove that $\sqrt a -\sqrt{a-1} <\sqrt{a-2} -\sqrt{a-3}.$

To prove this inequality, do I square both sides of this inequality? I tried to assume that $a$ is $3,$ but I don't think this way is optimal.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{t}-\sqrt{t-1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t} + \sqrt{t+1}}$

Comment: (1) Move the 2 Negative terms to other Sides :: We will get Positive terms. (2) Squaring now is Easier : Most terms will cancel out. (3) Square that now :: We will Directly get the Answer Quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Since $a\ge 3$, we have

\begin{align}
&\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{a-1}>\sqrt{a-2}+\sqrt{a-3}\\
\Leftrightarrow~~~&\frac{1}{\sqrt{a-2}+\sqrt{a-3}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{a-1}}\\
\Leftrightarrow~~~&\frac{\color{blue}{\sqrt{a-2}-\sqrt{a-3}}}{\underbrace{(\sqrt{a-2}+\sqrt{a-3})(\color{blue}{\sqrt{a-2}-\sqrt{a-3}})}_{\color{red}{1}}}>\frac{\color{blue}{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{a-1}}}{\underbrace{(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{a-1})(\color{blue}{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{a-1}})}_{\color{red}{1}}}\\
\Leftrightarrow~~~&\sqrt{a-2}-\sqrt{a-3}>\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{a-1}.
\end{align}

The proof is done.

---

(The solution is inspired by the Hint from @achillehui.)

Comment: thank you binchen and @achillehui ! :D and I'll learn to format this better when asking future questions. thanks again!